# Getting DEBUG: Crawled (504) error with Lua script While loop timing out for Scrapy-Splash

Tags: python, lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am very new to coding and am struggling with a web **scraper** I am trying to build. I am using a Lua script in order for my scrapy request to wait for any web-element (don't care about which element I just need the initial page loader to finish loading so I can access the html elements) to appear after the JavaScript on the website has loaded.  The particular website I am trying to access is https://www.ladbrokes.com.au/sports/basketball/usa/nba where it has a JS initial loader page before any of the elements on the website are loaded

my current code is this:

```
class Ladbrokes(scrapy.Spider):

      name = 'Ladbrokes'
      allowed_domains = ['ladbrokes.com.au']
      start_urls = ['https://www.ladbrokes.com.au/sports']

      def parse (self, response):
    
           sports_link = select_ladbrokes(response)

           for link in sports_link:
                url = response.urljoin(link)
                yield SplashRequest(url = url, callback =self.ladbrokes_all_comps,endpoint='execute', 
                            args={'lua_source':lua_script})
        
      
   
      def ladbrokes_all_comps(self, response):
           comps = response.xpath('//*[@id="accordion_4e099d27-0f11-4c6e-848e-965fff7ad995"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/text()').extract()
  
lua_script = '''        
   function main(splash)

      assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
      while not splash:select('#page-content-left > div > div') do
         splash:wait(0.1)
      end
      return {html=splash:html()}
    end '''
```

When I call my spider I end up getting these errors:

```
2019-11-25 16:41:30 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (504) <GET https://www.ladbrokes.com.au/sports/nrl via http://0.0.0.0:8050/execute> (referer: None)
2019-11-25 16:41:30 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <504 https://www.ladbrokes.com.au/sports/nrl>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
```

It seems it is timing out on the Lua script While loop, but I am not sure if it is because I am trying to select the web-element incorrectly.

I also tried putting in a long splash wait argument in the SplashRequest function, but it seemed the initial page loader never finished loading. Any help on this would be great!